# Insert data to database after validation

Tags: php, mysql

Im working in a php form where Im validating the feilds with regular expression. Validation working fine but I want to insert data into database after the validation finish with no error  I dont know how to rite this ?

Im facing a prolem and data is inserting empty records into database each time I click submit. Also , I want after the insert is done to redirect to a Thank you page .

I really appreciate your help and suggestion .

here is my code

```
<?php
  $errname     = "";
  $errage      = "";
  $errmobile   = "";

  if($_POST["ac"]=="login"){
    // Full Name must be letters, dash and spaces only
      if(preg_match("/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z -]+$/", $_POST["name"]) === 0)
      $errname = '<p class="errText">Please enter your full name </p>';
    // age must be 2 digits
    if(preg_match("/^\d{2}$/", $_POST["age"]) === 0)
      $errage = '<p class="errText">Age must be 2 digits</p>';
              // Mobile mask 050-0000000
    if(preg_match("/^\d{3}-\d{7}$/", $_POST["mobile"]) === 0)
      $errmobile = '<p class="errText">Mobile must be in this format: 050-0000000</p>';


      // contact to database

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Error , check your server connection.");

mysql_select_db("career_system");

 //Get data in local variable

$v_name=$_POST['name'];

$v_age=$_POST['age'];

$v_gender=$_POST['gender'];

$v_mobile =$_POST['mobile'];


$query="insert into applicant(name, age, gender, mobile ) values ('$v_name', '$v_age', '$v_gender','$v_mobile ')";

mysql_query($query)  or die(mysql_error());
}
echo "Your information has been received"; 
      }


  ?>

</head>

<body>
<div align="center">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<form name="form1" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="POST">
  <p>
    <input type="hidden" name="ac" value="login">
  </p>
  <table width="485" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="48">Full Name</td>
        <td width="150"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo      $_POST["name"]; ?>"></td>
        <td width="273"><?php  if(isset($errname)) echo $errname; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td><input name="age" type="text" id="age" value="<?php echo $_POST["age"]; ?>"></td>
        <td><?php  if(isset($errage)) echo $errage; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td><input name="gender" type="radio" value="Male" checked>
          Male 
          <input name="gender" type="radio" value="Female">
          Female</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mobile</td>
        <td><input name="mobile" type="text" id="mobile" value="<?php echo $_POST["mobile"]; ?>"></td>
        <td><?php  if(isset($errmobile)) echo $errmobile; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
        <input name="reset" type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset"></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use an `$errors` array and check for its emptiness before inserting:

```
$errors = array();

if ($_POST["ac"]=="login") {

    if (!preg_match("/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z -]+$/", $_POST['name']))
        $errors['name'] = '<p class="errText">Please enter your full name </p>';

    if (!preg_match("/^\d{2}$/", $_POST['age']))
        $errors['age'] = '<p class="errText">Age must be 2 digits</p>';

    // etc...

    if (!$errors) {
        $query = "
            insert into applicant 
            (name, age, gender, mobile ) 
            values 
            (
            '".mysql_real_escape_string($v_name)."', 
            '".mysql_real_escape_string($v_age)."', 
            '".mysql_real_escape_string($v_gender)."', 
            '".mysql_real_escape_string($v_mobile)."'
            )
        ";

        mysql_query($query);
    }

    // etc...
}

// Later in your HTML:

<tr>
    <td>Mobile</td>
    <td><input name="mobile" type="text" id="mobile" value="<?php echo $_POST["mobile"]; ?>"></td>
    <td><?php  if(isset($errors['mobile'])) echo $errors['mobile'] ?></td>
</tr>
```

Make sure to escape data before sending it to the database (hence, the `mysql_real_escape_string` calls)! An important piece of advice would be to actually abandon the `mysql_` functions as they are antiquated. You should use PDO instead. It's much easier, more efficient and eliminates much of the SQL injection threat with little effort:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb", 'username', 'password');
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die('Could not connect to database!');
}

$stm = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO applicant (name, age, gender, mobile ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
$stm->execute(array($v_name, $v_age, $v_gender, $v_mobile));
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a space after applicant - `INSERT INTO`applicant`(name, age, gender, mobile )`

Also, your code is insecure and your database is now vulnerable to attack. Make sure you escape all of your strings before you insert them into a db!

http://phptutorial.info/?mysql-real-escape-string

Answer (score -1):

How about something like:

```
  if($_POST["ac"]=="login"){
    // Full Name must be letters, dash and spaces only
      if(preg_match("/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z -]+$/", $_POST["name"]) === 0)
      $errname = '<p class="errText">Please enter your full name </p>';
    // age must be 2 digits
    if(preg_match("/^\d{2}$/", $_POST["age"]) === 0)
      $errage = '<p class="errText">Age must be 2 digits</p>';
              // Mobile mask 050-0000000
    if(preg_match("/^\d{3}-\d{7}$/", $_POST["mobile"]) === 0)
      $errmobile = '<p class="errText">Mobile must be in this format: 050-0000000</p>';


      // contact to database

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Error , check your server connection.");

mysql_select_db("career_system");

 //Get data in local variable

$v_name=$_POST['name'];

$v_age=$_POST['age'];

$v_gender=$_POST['gender'];

$v_mobile =$_POST['mobile'];

if($errname != "" || $errage != "" || $errmobile != "")
   echo "Error!";
else{

$query="insert into applicant(name, age, gender, mobile ) values ('$v_name', '$v_age', '$v_gender','$v_mobile ')";

    mysql_query($query)  or die(mysql_error());
}
}
```

And just for your own safety, when storing posted values into a database, always check that they are not some type of attack (like for example SQL injection) by using:

```
mysql_real_escape_string(param);
```

Comment: why connect to the database at all if there are errors in the submitted data?

Comment: @ceejayoz: I was not done writing. And the code is a copy of his code as a solution to his problem.

Comment: Submitted as a alternative solution, after I submitted I registered that his code is vulnerable to attacks, so I edited it. At the same time you gave me the comment...